# Say Set S = $\{{a+\frac b{2^n} : a,b,n ∈ℤ}\}$, what is wrong with defining $f: S → S$ as $f(a+\frac b{2^n})=a-\frac b{2^n}$ for $a, b, n ∈ ℤ$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Trying to get into more abstract maths. One of my first times properly getting into sets, and the textbook I have doesn't have answers or hints or anything.
The question is, if
Set *S* = $$\left\{{a+\frac{b}{2^n} : a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}}\right\}$$

what's wrong with defining the function *$f: S \to S$* as

$$f\left(a+\frac{b}{2^n}\right)=a-\frac{b}{2^n}$$ for $a, b, n ∈ \mathbb Z$?

(Also want to know what the point is of $f: S → S$? Is it saying that this function takes an element of $S$, and the range will always be another element of $S$?)

Comment: The proposed definition "f(a + (b/2^n)=a-b/2^n" has unbalanced parentheses.  That is the first thing wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry, wrote it out wrong. I've amended it.

Comment: There are still unbalanced parentheses. The expression does not parse. You have $f(a+b/2^n=a-b/2^n$. Not only do you lack a closing parentheses, making it difficult to tell what the argument of your function is, but you also use the 'backslash" notation making it difficult to tell what is the numerator. Does `a-b/2^n` mean $a - \frac{b}{2^n}$, or does it mean $\frac{a-b}{2^n}$, or something else? Who knows? You certainly don't seem to tell us.

Comment: Sorry. Changed. My first question, didn't know proper syntax.

Comment: Assume $n=0$. Then you have $f(a+b)=a-b$, which is not uniquely determined (eg, $f(4+1)=3=f(3+2)=1$. More generally, you would need $x=a+b/2^n$ to uniquely determine $(a,b,n)$, which it is unlikely to since you are running the risk of equal sums (4+1=3+2) or equal quotients (2/4 = 4/8).

Comment: You can write $2$ as e.g.  $2+0/2^1$ or $1+1/2^0$ and these lead to different values of $f$, so $f$ isn't well defined